# Store 3-dimensional table in database where 1 dimension increases over time

Tags: sql, database, google-app-engine, nosql, data-warehouse

I have a data set with three dimensions that I would like to store for use with a website:

1. A list of companies (about 1000)
2. Information about the company (about 15 things)
3. Time (monthly)

Essentially, I want to track this information over time and keep it up to date.

When I start, the data will be 1000x15x1, after a year it will be 1000x15x12, and after 10 years if will be 1000x15x120.

The main queries I would make are:

- Get all information for one company over all times
- Get all information for one particular time

What would be a good database configuration for doing this?  I'm open to either SQL or noSQL solutions.

In case it matters, the website is on Google App Engine.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please narrow it down

Comment: @K4M, could you please make a suggestion for making it more specific?

Comment: Are you referring to just database schema design or whole database infrastructure setup?

Answer (score 2):

**From the relational database schema design perspective:**

If the goal is analytics / ad-hoc querying / OLAP in general only, then you can use star-schema which is well suited for these type of analytics. But beware, OLAP databases are de-normalized and not suitable for operational transaction storage / OLTP in general, if you are planning to do both on this database.

The beauty of the Star schema:

- The [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse#Facts) tables are usually all numeric, making the tables very small even though there are too many records. Small table means it is very fast to read (I/O).
- All joins from the fact table to dimension tables are based on foreign keys (single column, numeric, indexable foreign keys)
- All dimension tables have surrogate key, which is a single column primary key. Single column primary key is easier to `JOIN` than a multi-column primary key  and also easier to index.
- There is no `NULL` in foreign keys in fact tables. This makes `JOIN` operations  straightforward, i.e. always `JOIN` fact table to all of its dimension tables. If you need `NULL` case, you need to add that as a special case in your dimension table. For example: if a company is not listed on stock market, and one of the thing you track is stock price, then you enter 0 or `NULL` into the fact for the stock price table depending on (how you want to do SUM(), AVG() etc later) and then add a special case into your StockSymbols dimension table called 'Private company' and add the foreign key of this special case into the fact table as your foreign key.
- Almost all filtering is done through the dimension tables that are much much smaller than the fact tables. This requires having a Date dimension to be able to do date-based queries.
- If you can stay in pure Star schema, then all yours `JOIN`s are single hop (i.e. no join between two tables through another table).

All these makes `JOIN` operations very fast, simple and straightforward. That's why the Star schema is at the heart of data-warehousing designs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse

One level up from this is OLAP (SSAS SQL Server Analyses Services for example) which does pre-processing of the data to make it fast to query but it involves more learning than pure start-schema and it's an overkill in your case

**For your example**

In Star schema,

- Companies will be a dimension table
- You will need Month [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(data_warehouse)) table.  It's simplified version of Date dimension, just for month info. An example of Date dimension is here.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho

- The information about the company (15 things you say) will be fact tables. The facts must be numeric (b/c ideally all non-numeric values is saved in dimension tables). This means taking the non-numeric part of a fact to a dimension table.  For example: if you are keeping revenue and would like to keep the currency type too, then the you will need a Currency dimension and save only the amount in the fact table and a foreign key to the Currency dimension table.
- If you have any non-numeric facts, you need to store the distinct list in a dimension table and add foreign key to that dimension table inside your Fact table (this is called [factless fact table](https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/factless-fact-table/)). The only exception to that is if the cardinality of the dimension and the fact table is very similar, then you can just store the non-numeric fact value inside the fact table directly as there is no benefit in having a dimension table (in fact a disadvantage).
- Also the facts can be grouped by their granularity. For example you could have company_monthly_summary fact table and keep more than one fact in that table (which are all joining to Company dimension and Month dimension). This is all up-to-you how you would like to group facts table. But if their granularity are not the same, they should not be grouped as that will cause sparse fact tables and harder to query.
- You will use foreign keys in Fact tables to join to your Dimension tables
- Add index for your Dimension tables' most used columns
- Add a numeric surrogate key to your dimension. It is usually an auto-increment number but that's up-to you. One exception people prefers for the surrogate key of Date dimension is using the format YYYYMMDD (as integer). This makes is easier on `WHERE` clause: i.e instead of filtering for the Date column (a DATETIME value), which will do search to find the surrogate keys, you just provide the surrogate keys directly b/c you know the format. Depending on your business domain, you may have other similar useful surrogate key patterns that you may want to consider and use. But just know, in case of a business domain change, you will have have to update all fact records. Simple auto-increment surrogate key does not have that problem. In your case, the surrogate key for the month can be actual month number (1 for Jan)

That being said, 1 million rows in 5 years is easy to query even without a Star-schema design (with proper indexing, database maintenance). But if this is part of a larger analytics system, then go with Star schema

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way.

Create a table, companyname + info you needto store + column for year-month.

Ex:

CREATE TABLE  `tablename` (

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

companyname varchar(255) ,

info1 int(11) NOT NULL,

info2 datetime ,

info3 varchar(255) ,

info4 bool ,

yearmonth datetime,
```

PRIMARY KEY (id) );

#queries

select * from tablename where companyname="nameofthecompany";

select * from tablename where yearmonth="year-month"; #can use between here